# How to send the dynamically added values to another url in Django

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a HTML page with two dropdowns and a button.The values in second dropdown are populated based on the value selected in first dropdown. When I click on the button, it navigates to a different url with the same form and some additional information.How can I populate the dropdown values there too?

Answer (score 0):

you can put name for our URLs and our app name, and then call it in HTML

for example :
url.py

```
url(r'^page1/$', views.page_num1, name='p1'),
url(r'^page2/$', views.page_num2, name='p2'),
```

views.py

```
def page_num1(request):
    return render(request, 'index1.html')
def page_num2(request):
    return render(request, 'index2.html')
```

HTML :

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
<a
class="dropdown-item"
href="{% url 'p1'%}"
>drop down item 1</a
>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'p2'%}"
>dropdown item 2</a
>

and this is full code for drop-down menu:

<li class="nav-item dropdown">
<a
class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
href="{% url '#'%}"
id="navbarDropdown"
role="button"
data-toggle="dropdown"
aria-haspopup="true"
aria-expanded="false"
>###</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
<a
class="dropdown-item"
href="{% url 'p1'%}"
>#####</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'p2'%}">####</a>
```

and finally, if you have an app so you should add in url.py:

```
app_name = 'your app name'
```

and included inside the link

for example:
urls.py

```
app_name='test'
```

HTML:

###

Comment: in the views,I see you are giving two templates.I have only one HTML template

Comment: in this case, you could make a decision about the value in views.py and then send 'Context' to our HTML files.

Comment: this video I think is very usefully: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h05UEays2KI